# Google Search Console fetch and render reports pages are partially rendered due to Doubleclick an then they are not indexed

Tags: seo, google

I'm a newbie website (WordPress) owner and having an issue about google rendering one of my posts.

I log in to Search Console > Crawl > Fetch as Google > introduce my URL and hit "Fetch and Render". It says **"Partial"** although my all other posts were indexed as "Complete" without any problem until now.

When I click into the details, Search Console says:

```
URL                                                  Type   Reason   Severity   
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js Script Blocked  Low       robots.txt
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id        AJAX   Blocked  Low       robots.txt
```

My post isn't indexed. Nothing is scarier than this. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are many people around the web who have had this problem it seems.

When I visited https://static.doubleclick.net/robots.txt I see that it is blocking all bots from crawling its content. This means that fetch and render should not be able to crawl it for anyone using doubleclick and so there should be no cause for alarm. Googlebot understands what doubleclick is of course.

On the other hand, this error seems somewhat unusual, but others have had it. One person said his site started deranking after receiving tens of thousands of these errors on his site from the same issue you're having regarding doubleclick.

The severity of this error is reported to you as "Low" which should indicate that it's not much of a concern.

Ultimately, I think that it's possible that Google is reporting this as an error to you because an error on its own end. Whether or not this could effect the indexing of your page or ranking of your site I'm unsure of as there doesn't seem to be that much information out there on this issue.

You may want to consider removing the doubleclick code from that specific page if possible to prevent this error from continuing.

Here are some related posts in the Google forums that may give you some more information:
http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/webmasters/qNLbhXKJfTc
http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/webmasters/_dxNiJdGiG0
http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/adsense/aJkjeSBw1yI

Answer (score 0):

`doubleclick.net` is probably powering the ads in your site.  The fact that Google can't render some ads shouldn't mean that it doesn't index your pages.

Non-indexed pages are usually caused by other problems such as duplicate content.   When Google finds two pages that have the same text, it usually picks one to index and ignores the other.   See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

In WordPress this is usually because listing pages such as the home page, tag pages, and category pages are configured to show entire posts rather than snippets.   This causes Google to sometimes index those listing pages instead of the individual blog post pages.  The easiest way to solve the problem is by using the `<!--more-->` tag in every blog post.  Insert that tag after the first couple sentences and only the part before the tag will show up on listing pages.   See https://en.support.wordpress.com/more-tag/

Answer (score 0):

Actually these resources are for add and analytics code and  Google need not to crawl them as they are to crawl your content not their.
They also block the resources from being crawled by the search engines as these are not from your site and for security purposes.